# Bootstrap 3, how to create a navbar with a brand image and two rows of links?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I can't understand how to code this nav with bootstrap:

[image: navbar]

As you can see it composed of a brand image on the left, some space and then the two rows that should fit the brand length and should also fit the window width.
I did this but it doesn't work fine. When i resize the window sometimes nav goes off of the window.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="nav">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="navbar-header"> <a href="#"><img src="~/Images/logo.png" class="logo" width="308" height="130" alt="" style="float:left; margin-left:20px;margin-right:100px;"></a> </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the [Default navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) from the Bootstrap's documentation.

1. Turn the brand image into a simple non-floating block.
2. Leave an empty space on the right side only.
3. Wrap all menu items into one `<ul></ul>` but make them higher.
4. Force the 5th element to start new line. <strike>Clear a mind, open a heart</strike>. All items are left-floating, so `clear: left;` will be enough.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.navbar-brand {
  display: block;            /* 1. */
  float:   none;
  height:  auto;
  margin:  0 !important;     /* 2. */
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav>li>a {         /* 3. */
    line-height:    21px;
    padding-top:    22px;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
  }

  .clear-left {              /* 4. */
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/308x130/c69/f9c/?text=Brand" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li class="clear-left"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above HTML file, modify `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` to
`<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">`
and you are done putting it to right side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CSS Flexbox** for this. This will help you solve all your vertical and horizontal centering/spacing issues as well.

Have a look at this **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOMZjd)**.

Or have a look at the snippet below (*Use full screen while previewing to view the desktop view*):

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.navbar-content-holder {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  flex: 1;
}

.custom-nav-links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-header {
    flex: 1;
  }
  
  .navbar-collapse {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 30px;
    background: #F8F8F8;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-content-holder">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <div class="navbar-right custom-nav-links">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar-content-holder -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!